# How to print a particular line from the command prompt output using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os
gsize = os.system('dir dir C:\Users\GNK\Documents')
```

Which will give out put as below. but i want to print only last 2 lines.

```
C:\Users\GNK>dir C:\Users\GNK\Documents
06/26/2017  04:24 PM            13,826 1.xlsx
07/03/2017  10:52 PM            15,068 2.xlsx
08/11/2017  05:59 PM         3,227,457 3.zip
08/14/2017  02:56 PM               527 4.sql
06/09/2017  02:36 PM             3,976 5.sql
06/09/2017  02:54 PM           601,580 6.zip
06/12/2017  07:59 PM       116,641,792 7.mp3
08/12/2017  09:25 AM        15,747,576 8.exe
06/16/2017  12:23 AM           286,829 9
08/19/2017  02:38 PM         1,211,008 10
07/21/2017  08:08 AM            98,776 11
08/03/2017  10:38 PM        10,427,892 11
06/04/2017  05:20 PM           196,126 12
05/21/2017  09:11 AM           196,126 13
06/04/2017  05:22 PM           232,964 14
05/21/2017  09:11 AM           232,964 15
07/07/2017  12:03 PM            13,077 16
07/07/2017  12:02 PM            13,076 v17t
07/06/2017  07:57 AM        49,400,720 18
05/23/2017  12:56 AM           551,522 19
             160 File(s)    921,950,736 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  21,563,650,048 bytes free
```

I want to print only last 2 lines. how can I do this. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) doc you can read:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions
>   with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for
>   some helpful recipes.

So I think would be better for you do something like:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(['dir', 'C:\Users\GNK\Documents']).splitlines()[-2:])
```

The `.splitlines()[-2:]` part is to keep just the last two lines. You can join them to form a two line string if you want with:

```
str.join('\n', subprocess.check_output(['dir', 'C:\Users\GNK\Documents']).splitlines()[-2:])
```

Comment: Thanks. I Tried that it was throwing an error. was not able to fix that. please find below that error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g_size.py", line 4, in <module>
    proc1 = subprocess.Popen('git.cmd dir')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @GNK From where you are running the script? I read in your error output 'git.cmd dir', pls try to run the script outside whatever git shell you have. The other thing to try is to add the `shell=True` parameter to the `subprocess.check_output` func.

Comment: Tried changing the function and ran outside the git cmd. still no luck. error as below. File "g_size.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(subprocess.check_output(['dir', 'C:\Users\gnk' 'shell=True']).splitlines()[-2:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: `print(subprocess.check_output(['dir', 'C:\Users\gnk' 'shell=True'])` is not good ;) it should be like: `print(subprocess.check_output(['dir', 'C:\Users\gnk'], shell=True)`. The `shell=True` is an extra parameter to the `check_output` func, not part of the first parameter (that is a list). I don't have a windows machine near of me now, that is whyI'm kind of blind here.